# Is Spectral Coherence (MSC) dependent to the initial amplitude of the comparing signals?

Tags: power-spectral-density, synchronization, coherence

Given the signals

\begin{align}
x(t) &= A_1\sin(\omega t)\\
y(t) &= A_2\sin(\omega t)
\end{align}

Do $A_1$ and $A_2$ play a role in the $C_{xy}$ coherence estimator? MATLAB's `mscohere.m` shows no differences for $A_1=A_2$ and $A_1\neq A_2$ at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(signal_processing)#Definition_and_Formulation) of the (magnitude-squared) coherence

$$C_{xy}(f)=\frac{|G_{xy}(f)|^2}{G_{xx}(f)G_{yy}(f)}$$

with the cross-spectral density $G_{xy}(f)$, and the power spectra $G_{xx}(f)$ and $G_{yy}(f)$, respectively, it is clear that scaling of $x(t)$ or $y(t)$ does not change the value of $C_{xy}(f)$, because the scaling constants appear in the numerator as well as in the denominator and cancel out.

The coherence is a normalized quantity (and hence scaling-invariant), and it always satisfies $0\le C_{xy}(f)\le 1$.

Comment: Thank you. I know it may sounds a naive question to make, however in a very popular paper [IF 29.2] that is clearly stated as in "Coherence mixes the effects of amplitude and phase in the interrelations between two signals".

Comment: @IDKreally And now you do know really. :D